# Displaying local storage values in a text-area with react-hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a note taking app in React.

I have managed to save state on local storage.

My goal is to display the local storage 'notes' in the `textarea` on render and refresh. So far on refresh the place holder is displayed on render.

I want to:

- If no notes in local storage display place holder
- If notes are present in local then display them in the text area.

Heres the code:

```
const [notes, setNotes] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
  const notes = localStorage.getItem("notes")
  if (notes) {
    setNotes(JSON.parse(notes))
  }
})

const handleChange = e => {
  setNotes(e.target.value)
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(e.target.value))
}

return (
  <form>
    <label for="pad">
      <span>Add your notes</span>
      <textarea
        rows="10"
        placeholder="Add notes here "
        name="pad"
        onChange={handleChange}
      ></textarea>
    </label>
  </form>
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use textarea `value` with `notes` variable.
You don't need useEffect for this example.
Even if you want to use it please add your dependency array.

```
export default function App() {
  const localNotes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState(localNotes);

  const handleChange = e => {
    localStorage.setItem("notes", e.target.value);
    setNotes(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <label for="pad">
        <span>Add your notes</span>
        <textarea
          rows="10"
          placeholder="Add notes here "
          name="pad"
          value={notes}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Working example https://codesandbox.io/s/still-moon-bmuof

Comment: Perfect because the placeholder doesn't flash on render before showing notes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1) You should bind the `notes` state to `TextArea`'s value props.

2) You need to add an empty array as the dependency array for the `useEffect` hook, such that the method within it will only run once when the component is rendered. This will ensure that the state is updated with the values from `localStorage` when the component is mounted.

```
const [notes, setNotes] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
  const notes = localStorage.getItem("notes")
  if (notes) {
    setNotes(notes)
  }
}, [])

const handleChange = e => {
  const { value } = target
  setNotes(e.target.value)
  localStorage.setItem("notes", value))
}

return (
  <form>
    <label for="pad">
      <span>Add your notes</span>
      <textarea
        rows="10"
        placeholder="Add notes here "
        name="pad"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={notes}
      ></textarea>
    </label>
  </form>
)
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` does not make sense for textarea's value that is already a string